# Jquery using focusout & on click together doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to achieve the result when i am typing inside input the list will drop down.
if the list is clicked then will give out an alert.
in the same time if the input is focus out , it will hide the list.
But the problem is when on click , it doesn't work.

```
$("input").on("keyup",function(){
$(".abc li").show();
});
$(".abc li").on("click",function(){
    alert("123");
});
$("input").focusout(function(){
$(".abc").find("li").hide();
});
```

Reference to my code
http://jsfiddle.net/8t7erade/

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery .focusout / .click conflict](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13980448/jquery-focusout-click-conflict)

Answer (score 3):

Your click event is never getting called because the `li` is hidden by your `focusout` event before it can be triggered.

You could set a timeout to allow for the click to be registered:

```
$("input").focusout(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(".abc").find("li").hide()
    }, 100)
});
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8t7erade/1/)

Answer (score 0):

How about setting (short) time out on blur (focus out)?

Like this:

```
$("input").on("keyup",function(){
$(".abc li").show();
});
$(".abc li").on("click",function(){
    alert("123");
});
$("input").focusout(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){$(".abc").find("li").hide();}, 150);//i set 150 just as example

});
```

Problem is that blur occurs first, and at that time elements got hidden and mouse event is passed to other (visible) element.