# Click event on button not fired after focus out

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-events

Please See the image for clear understanding of problem:

[image: here].

There is `focusout` event on boxes. While typing in the box, if a user clicks on buttons the `click` does not work as focus out called immediately and button moves up a bit when `focusout` from the box. I just came to know in advance how to fire click event of buttons just after `focusout`. Here is sample code on `focusout`.

```
$(document).on("focusout", ".fn-enlargeTextarea", function(event) {
     var optionNumber = ($(this).attr('id').replace('1option','')).trim();
     $('#1option'+optionNumber+'_counter').remove();
     $(this).removeClass('textarea-height01').addClass('textarea-height02');     
});
```

Comment: could you use .blur() instead of .on("focusout")?

Comment: problem remains same @oompahlumpa

Comment: so on focusout you want to trigger a click event of a button correct?

Comment: only if focusout caused by click on any of the buttons.@oompahlumpa

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery .focusout / .click conflict](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13980448/jquery-focusout-click-conflict)

Comment: @GrégoireFruleux it is not duplicate probably you interpreted in other ways.

Comment: It doesn't have enough time to get the click to trigger since the button moves position.

Either  position the button so it doesn't get moved on focusout or use 'mousedown' instead of 'click'.

Comment: Not much, did you had a look at the other thread ? There is conflict between FocusOut and Click, as the other one ! And the answer provide working code (well, sadly not a beautiful one but it doesn't seems to be a real one)

Comment: @GrégoireFruleux  click event on buttons only should be fire if button clicks.But it does not fire only focus out calls.It works when focus is somewhere else within the window.

Comment: plz share the markup, so that it could be helpful to understand what is closest target when button is tried to be clicked but it moved.

Comment: Hi Did you find a solution for this? I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can stop propagation and then call click on button. I did this [here](https://jsfiddle.net/3kynsq2r/)

```
event.stopPagation();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger events using jquery. If you'd like to fire the click event of buttons just after focusout, add the following line:

```
$( "#targetElm" ).trigger( "click" );
```

inside your callback function that runs on focusout.