# Blazor - Prevent sibling event from firing ( onclick > onfocusout )

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm creating my own autocomplete input in Blazor. (something like below)

```js
function FocusOut()
{
  document.getElementById("list-item-one").innerHTML = "Focus out";
}

function Click()
{
  document.getElementById("list-item-one").innerHTML = "Click";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="search" onfocusout="FocusOut()" />
<ul class="dropdown">
  <li id="list-item-one" onclick="Click()">List Item One</li>
</ul>
```

When I click on the list item, the onfocusout event fires instead of the onclick event. Is there a way to "push" the onclick event?

This isn't a parent child relation, so "stopPropagation" has no effect. Also I know there is a `datalist` tag, but i'm not using it because of the way it look, feels and behaves in the different browsers.

Comment: Can you add the function implementations to the question? If you remove the ```Clear()``` function and replace it with some empty void function, does it work?

Comment: No it does not, it's only a void that sets the bool "showDropdown" to false.

Comment: Update your question with code or create a fiddle so we can test solutions.

Comment: At first sight, the problem is that ```onclick``` executes after the ```onfocusout``` event, at which point the dropdown is closed. Try replacing ```onclick``` with ```onmousedown```, but depending on what you want to do, you might not want the dropdown to close...

Comment: I have updated my code with working javascript. There the events execute after each other. But that being said, the onmousedown instead of onclick works like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the order of events is `OnMouseDown`, `OnFocusOut`, `OnClick`.

Because of this, your dropdown closes before the `OnClick` event, so the click is not registered.

A working solution is to replace `OnClick` with `OnMouseDown`.

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47944833/6771464) answer by @DuncanLuk.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and I added a `await Task.Delay(250)` in my `@onfocusout` handler and it worked. You can find the live demo by clicking three vertical dots at top right in [ilovedotnet site](https://ilovedotnet.org).

[image]

```
<section id="social">
    <div class="dropdown is-right @(MenuCollapsed ? null : "is-active")" @onclick="ToggleMenu" @onfocusout="FocusOutHandler">
        <div class="dropdown-trigger">
            <button class="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-controls="social-menu">
                Social
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" id="social-menu" role="menu">
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="https://ilovedotnet.org/" target="_blank" class="dropdown-item">
                    I Love DotNet
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

@code {
    internal bool MenuCollapsed { get; private set; } = true;

    internal void ToggleMenu()
    {
        MenuCollapsed = !MenuCollapsed;
    }

    internal async Task FocusOutHandler()
    {
        // to avoid race between mouse click of anchor tag Navigation. without this delay Navigation
        // is not getting executed when item is clicked from mouse
        await Task.Delay(250);
        MenuCollapsed = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Using `Task.Delay(250)` is just ignoring the problem, not solving it.